# Joomla: Some module to show more than one random images

Tags: image, joomla, random, module

Do you know some module in Joomla, which shows more than one (e.g. 4) random images? Like on the page http://www.fightnews.sk/. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an extensions from the [Image Rotators](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/rotators/images-rotators) category on JED. Maybe something like this one might suit your needs:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/rotators/images-rotators/18753